# OperatorFunction<unknown, unknown> is missing the following properties from type 'Observable': _isScalar, source, operator,

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I'm having a problem while implementing the getProducts() method for HTTP requests in Angular. I set the observable to match my interface `Observable<IProduct[]>` to get and return products in the JSON file from `productUrL`, but it throws an error:

```
Type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, unknown>' is missing the following properties from 
type 'Observable<IProduct[]>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.
```

Here is `product.service.ts`

```
export class ProductService {
  public productUrl = "/api/products/roducts.json"

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this.http.get<IProduct[]>(this.productUrl)
    .pipe(
      tap(data => console.log("All: " + JSON.stringify(data)))),
      catchError(this.handleError)

  }

  private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse){
    let errorMessage = "";
    if(err.error instanceof ErrorEvent){
      errorMessage = "An error occured " +err.error.message; 
    }
    else{
      errorMessage = "Server returned core " + err.status +" error message is " + err.message 
    }
    console.error(errorMessage)
    return throwError(errorMessage)
  }
}
```

And here is `produst-list.component` which is calling the method `onInit`

```
 errorMessage: string;
 products: IProduct[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.productService.getProducts().subscribe({
      next: products => this.products = products,
      error: err => this.errorMessage = err
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.pipe(
  tap(data => console.log("All: " + JSON.stringify(data))),
  catchError(this.handleError)
)
```

try this, on first glance, looks like catchError should be within pipe.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is propably becouse of this line:

```
tap(data => console.log("All: " + JSON.stringify(data))))
```

You can use arrow functions (or anonymous), but you have to remember that if you are not putting code into brackets `{}` it means you are returning result of this code. 
It means, that your code is the same as:

```
tap(data => {
return console.log("All: " + JSON.stringify(data)))
   }
);
```

I am also talking about this one:

```
  next: products => this.products = products,
  error: err => this.errorMessage = err
```